# Wordpress plugin or Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a wordpress website, and i am going to create a "Meet The Team" page.

We have our own custom built system internally which has users and their positions in the company already in the database so i will be using this information.

I am unsure whether to make a wordpress plugin to display this data or just simply create a page template to display it.

Does anyone have any ideas what would be best or does it really not matter?

Comment: Creating a plugin seems like overkill in this instance, especially if you are going to be mixing assets like CSS/JS. If you want a completely independant package to either prevent theme editors from fiddling or to serve the same module to multiple websites then you should make it a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the team is probably not that likely to change often I would say go with a Page Template. The main benefit being that in the future you might want to teak it a bit (sort members in a particular fashion, have different sized avatars, etc) and doing these changes would be much easier if its just a page template. If your team changes often and there is a lot of dynamic data you pretty much have to go with the plugin though